# Iron Speed Designer

Tags: asp.net, ironspeed

I have a problem when changing table column name in Iron Speed Designer.

I made Accept changes for selected table to apply the change but I have problem.

I saw on the Iron Speed web site that I must use the Map Field dialog from the Databases tab.  However, I couldn't find this option on Databases tab.

Comment: Hi, We need to know which version of Iron Speed you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Some times it happens to me also..


But I use Rebuild All and some times I have to use Regenerate and Reload Stored Procedures.

That solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how in version 8.
Rename the field in the DB. Scan for schema changes. 
Then go to the databases tab. 
Find your field, it should show the old name as (deleted) and the new name as (added).
Select the new version. Then in the properties pane on the right at the top you should see a "Map field to" option. Click the three dots at the end and you should get a box pop up there you can select the old field.

Hope that helps.